# Issue with setting up docked cells

Tags: docked-cell

Normally I try to stay away from asking RTFM- questions but concerning docked cells I am currently groping in the dark. The documentation examples tell me how to create a new window containing a docked cell, but not how to setup a cell as docked cell in my existing .nb file. Am I to use (edit) the notebooks stylesheet or is there a command like e.g. SetOptions for that matter?

Comment: Ummm... what is RTFM?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork it is short for "Read the f*ing manual" and a typical internet response to basic questions for which the answer can easily be found in the usage manual :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {DockedCells}] =  Cell["XXXX", "DockedCell"]
```

or

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> Cell["XXXX", "DockedCell"]]
```

example:

```
buttons =  Row[{Button["Print Date", Print[DateString[]]], 
      Button["New Document", CreateDocument[{}]]}];
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {"DockedCells"}] =
       Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[buttons]], "DockedCell"]
```

See also the tutorial [Introduction to Toolbars](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToToolbars.html) for detailed examples like the one that gives:

[image]